# MSTest invokes contructor everytime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I got a unit test (MStest)
There is a test class that has a lot of test methods.
If I run all methods from TestExplorer, each method will invoke the constructor.
Is there any way to save TestClass instance across all of these methods?

Comment: Why does your test class have a constructor? what are you doing in it? If you want to run setup stuff, it should be done in a method with the attribute `OneTimeSetup` on it which will be run once for each fixture. or `Setup` which will run before every test

Comment: Apologies I think those are NUnit specific. But MSTest has a similar concept https://www.automatetheplanet.com/mstest-cheat-sheet/  
AssemblyInitialize (once per assembly),
     ,ClassInitialize (once per test class class)
          ,TestInitialize (before each test of the class)

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, there are multiple different attributes that indicate when a method should be invoked. When you want a setup to run only once for all tests, you should use the `ClassInitialize` -attribute, not the constructor:

```
[TestClass]
class MyTests
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void SetupTests(TestContext context) { ... }
}
```

Performing initializations from within the constructor is merely a bad idea, as every test-framework has its own plan on when and how often to invoke those. Instead you should use the attributes which are deterministic in their use.

If you need initialization to happen before every test, you may use the `TestInitialize`-attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Please update your answer, you need to add a parameter TestContext.